# Prevent sideway scroll of site in mobile safari

Tags: iphone, mobile, jquery-mobile, mobile-safari, viewport

I have a website based on jQuery Mobile. 
I'm using the viewport tag to fit my site to screen size.

So far so good.

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

But the Problem is now, that I'm still able to scroll my whole site (the whole mobile safari browser) around the screen.

I tried to set

```
body {
   overflow:hidden;
}
```

like described in other posts here. But it does not work for me. Anyone an idea how to fix that?

Comment: You'll find the site up [here](http://www.m.fdl.de/%20property/ein-paradies-fur-kinder-ein-traum-fur-erwachsene).Thanks for your help!

Comment: The initial load on your mobile site is pretty heavy, approx. 700KB. There are also some 404 errors you probably want to fix.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and ended up using this workaround:

```
document.ontouchmove = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
};
```

Comment: doesn't solve it. this prevents all scrolling, not horizontal scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Well zooming and scrolling doesn't always have to be related. Your problem here is not with the viewport but with the actual width of your site, if the size is wider than the screen size you will have scrolling issues. You would have to give us a live example so we can help you to find the elements that are overflowing your layout

Comment: You'll find the site up [here](http://www.m.fdl.de/%20property/ein-paradies-fur-kinder-ein-traum-fur-erwachsene).Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I compared your site with one of our own. You're using jQuery Mobile 1.0RC1 and we're using 1.0b3. The problem occurs with your site but not with ours.

Maybe try upgrading to the latest jQuery Mobile?

Comment: I'm using **jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.js** and this is the newest one.

Answer (score 0):

As Jasper pointed out, you have a 404 while trying to fetch these:

- http://www.m.fdl.de/wp-content/themes/jquerymobile-FDL%202/img/cursors/grab.png (image)
- http://www.m.fdl.de/wp-content/themes/jquerymobile-FDL2/wp_properties.css?ver=1.13 (page)
- http://www.m.fdl.de/wp-content/themes/jquerymobile-FDL%202/js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js (jQuery Library)

You look like you have a space in a folder name "jquerymobile-FDL 2", I would rename this without the space.

Also I'm not sure if you can have a meta tag inside the title or style tags, maybe move all meta tags to the start pf your head tag?

- http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_meta.asp

Also you seem to be importing two different versions of jQuery

- http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.min.js?ver=3.2.1
- http://www.m.fdl.de/wp-content/themes/jquerymobile-FDL%202/js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js

Comment: Yeah, you and Jasper are right. There's some waste left from testing. I renamed my folder and want to clean up my stuff now. But I think this is not a solution for my scrolling problem?

Comment: let us know when you have a updated copy to view/test. Also RC2 is also out which might fix the issue as well

Comment: Expect this stuff "wp_properties.css?ver=1.13" (I couldn't figure out yet where it is generated) I've cleaned up all of the 404 errors. Im using the RC2.

Comment: Could I get a new URL for your example as the one you provided is still running RC1, well the CSS is still RC1

Comment: Also is there anyway to move the viewpoint to be the first tag within the head? Not sure if order of operations play into this

Comment: Ok, I moved the viewport to the top in the header and changed the CSS to RC2 like you recommended. But with no success. :( But i figured out, that I don't have this strange viewport sideway scrolling fault on every page. So on [this](http://www.m.fdl.de/wir-suchen-fur-sie) one here everything seems to be nice, expect to the point I made an selection with the Buttons. From this point on the content zoomed in. Very strange!

Comment: I would compare the two <head> sections and see what's different. Might be one of the JS/CSS Libs you're adding that's causing the viewpoint issue